# Angularjs, How make checkbox array to insert in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb, checkbox

I created a collection in mongoDB call  **Mangas**, which has " **name**, **autor,** genre  and  **info** "

**Gender is array.**

I have a form that will receive the name values, and autor info, the Checkbox to come as Array filled with values to be entered in the form

**Question.**

How to make a **checkbox** that has 2 options ** "**Adventure** ** and ** **Action**" ** and enter the mongoDB as array?

Same collection below.

MongoDB **Mangas**

```
db.mangas.insert({
    nome:'Toriko',
    autor:'não sei',
    gender:['adventure','action'],
    info:'...'
    })
```

**Index.html**

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.nome"></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.autor"></td>
  <!-- aqui precisa ser a CHECKBOX que irá ter os valores do array e inseridos no GENDER -->
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.info"></td>



  <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addManga()">Add manga</button></td>
</tr>

     <tr ng-repeat="manga in mangas">
       <td>{{manga.nome}}</td>
       <td>{{manga.autor}}</td>
       <td><!-- aqui vai listar o valor recebido do checkbox --></td>
       <td>{{manga.info}}</td>
     </tr>
```

**Function addManga**

```
$scope.addManga = function() {
    console.log($scope.manga);
    $http.post('/mangas', $scope.manga).success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
       refresh();
    })};
```